# from one dimensional Gaussian to two dimensional Gaussian

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given $x$ is a random variable, which is one-dimensional Gaussian distributed, such that
$$ x \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2).$$
Given $\theta$ is some constant, what would be the density function for 
$$ \mathbf y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \end{bmatrix}x?$$
Thank you!

Comment: What is $v$????

Comment: I've seen this called a "wrapped normal distribution".  Just what you mean by the "distribution function" is a question to ponder.  The cumulative distribution function in $\mathbb R^2$?  That doesn't seem very interesting.  The density function on the circle?  Perhaps, but I'd have called that the density function.  Some sort of c.d.f. on the circle?  That would probably lack a closed form.

Comment: @Batman : Good question.  I wrote my comment above just thinking $x$ appeared where $v$ appears.

Comment: The title is misleading.  "Two-dimensional Gaussian" is a term with a standard meaning, and this distribution supported on a circle is certainly not it.  A two-dimensional Gaussian, in the standard sense of the term, has a mean that is a point in $\mathbb R^2$ and a variance that is a matrix in $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$, and is unbounded.  This distribution is obviously bounded.

Comment: Hi @Batman, $v$ is supposed to be $x$. I had a typo in my post. Now it is fixed.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You are right. $v$ should be $x$. I mean the density function of $\mathbf y$, and the post is fixed. Thank you. I think it would be a density function on a line, given $\theta$ is a constant. Also, I think the density function is unbounded since $x$ is unbounded.

Comment: That $x$ is an unbounded random variable means that the _domain_ of the density function is unbounded; it does not mean that the density function itself is unbounded.  A function is called unbounded if its _image_ is an unbounded set, not if its domain is an unbounded set.  At any rate, the random variable $\mathbf y$ is bounded since it lies within a circle.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank you very much for your quick response. I know where my previous post causes the confusion. I did not want to put $x$ in the cosine/sine function. I have fixed the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random vector $\mathbf y$ has no density since $P(\mathbf y\in D)=1$ where $D$ is the line of the $(y_1,y_2)$-plane with equation $(\sin\theta)y_1=(\cos\theta)y_2$, which has Lebesgue measure zero.